# Access .net core application running on k3s on a raspberry pi

Tags: asp.net, kubernetes, raspberry-pi, k3s

I currently got my hands on a new raspberry pi 4 and wanted to host my application on a k3s installed on that pi.
So i installed k3s, build an .net core api (just a new project) and created a deployment. Everything is working, the app starts and the pod is running without any errors.

My current problem is that i want to access that running .net core api in the pod from my local computer.

So i added an ingress to route every request to my running pod
[image]

But when i call the ip of my raspberry on my local computer i get an 404 so there is something i am missing here.

Maybe someone can point me in the right direction where to look at.

Thanks in advance

- Deployed multiple ingress configurations
- Tried other ports